# Method not finding public list instantiated in the same class C#

Tags: c#

I have instantiated a list. C# cannot find the list from within the same class.

I have added a PNG so you can see the intellisense and code highlighting. Along with the code. I note that I may not be adding to the list correctly, but that is not what I am worried about for the moment. What i'm having trouble with is the Update() function not highlighting the type in the arguments and TurnsLog list not being found from within the update function. It could be a syntax error with brackets or a semi-colon basic stuff, but I cannot spot what is wrong with it. Also it is instantiated in another class.

[image]

Source for Copy pasta.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace DumbDnD

{
    public class Log
    {
        public void Initialize()
        {
            public List<GameplayState> TurnsLog = new List<GameplayState>();
        }


        public void Update(GameplaySate state)
        {
           TurnsLog.Add(GameplayState state);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you meant the list to be a member variable. As it is, you've declared it as a local variable within the `Initialize` method.

```
public class Log
{
    public List<GameplayState> TurnsLog = new List<GameplayState>();

    public void Update(GameplaySate state)
    {
       TurnsLog.Add(GameplayState state);
    }
}
```

See also [control variable scope and logic using code blocks in c#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/csharp-code-blocks/)

Comment: It is not even a valid local declaration, as local variables cannot have accessors such as public.

Comment: @jason.kaisersmith Yes, that is one of these reasons I think he meant to declare a member variable.

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was simple. Appreciate it.